# Prove that every sequence with infinite range in a certain topological space X converges to all of X

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ generated by the basis $\mathbf{B}=${$B_n:n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} where $B_n$={$n+k:k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup${$0$}}. After proving that $\mathbf{B}$ is in fact a basis for a topology and that $\mathcal{T}$ is not Hausdorff, we have to prove that every sequence in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ with infinite range converges to every point in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ under the topology $\mathcal{T}$. It is exercise 2.14 from Colin Adams' Introduction to Topology.

I guess that it is true since the problem says "prove" instead of "say if it is true or false", but I am not sure if this is a counterexample:

Let $x_n =
  \begin{cases}
    n/2       & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is even}\\
    1  & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is odd}
  \end{cases}
$

and consider the sequence {$x_n$}. This sequence clearly has $\mathbb{Z}^+$ as range and therefore has infinite range. Now consider $B_2$. It is clearly an open set in $\mathcal{T}$ and since $2\in B_2$, it is a neighbourhood of 2. However, there is no N $\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that for all n $\geq$ N happens that $x_n \in B_2$, and therefore {$x_n$} doesn't converge to 2.
Finally, {$x_n$} is a sequence with infinite range in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ that doesn't converge to all points of $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

What is going on? Am I misunderstanding the definition of infinite range or convergence? Is the book wrong? There is another exercise in the book very similar to this one, in the way that we are also working with an infinite range sequence that should converge to every point in the topological space but I found a "counterexample" just like this one. What am I missing?

Comment: My guess is that they don't mean converges, but rather, has those points as limit points.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the problem is wrong.

This topology is usually called the finite complement topology.

Given a sequence $x_n$ in this topology the following happens:

- If $x_n$ takes at least two values infinitely many times, then $x_n$ does not have any limit point.
- If $x_n$ takes exactly one value infinitely many times, then that value is the only limit of the sequence.
- If $x_n$ does not take any value infinitely many times, then every element in your set ($\mathbb Z$ in this case) is a limit point for $x_n$.

I think that in this case the authors mistaken "takes each value (at most) finitely many times" for "infinite range".